# How can you use facetting and groups with mutliple data sets in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two dataframes Data1 and Data2. Data1 has Date and Price and Ticker. Data2 has date and Volume and Ticker.The two dataframes are different length. That is, the Dates cannot be matched one-to-one so I can't put them into one dataframe without interpolating.

I want to plot Price versus Date and Volume versus date on the same plot which I guess means different layers and different scales. But I also want to facet on ticker.

How do I do this in ggplot2 without resorting to for loops?

Comment: Can you give us sample data from both datasets so we can actually work with a reproducible example? Paste the results of `dput(head(Data1))` and `dput(head(Data2))` in your answer, please.

Comment: I can't actually because what I described is a simplification of what I am really doing and it is private data.

Comment: @Dave31415 Generate random data and give the columns made up names.

Comment: I think I figured it out though. I can rowbind the two dataframes if I change the names of the variables to match. That is, rename Volume as Price and date as Date. I just need to add a variable to each that marks them as coming from different datasets. Then I can facet on "Ticker" and group on the new tag. I'll also have to ensure that the date formats are same. But it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your data would help, but I think this should work. I made the two data sets different colors, but doing things this way does not automatically produce a legend and the y-axis is labeled with only the first variable.

```
ggplot(Data1, aes(Date, Price)) + facet_wrap(~ Ticker) + geom_line(color="blue") + geom_line(data=Data2, aes(date, Volume), color="red")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my answer using my idea expressed above in comment.

```
ticks=c('JNJ','IBM','MSFT','GOOG','CAT','BAC') 
N1=100 
N2=200
Data1=data.frame(x=runif(N1),y=cumsum(runif(N1)),
                 ticks=sample(ticks,N1,replace=T), tag='data1')
Data2=data.frame(x=runif(N2),y=cumsum(runif(N2)),
                 ticks=sample(ticks,N2,replace=T),tag='data2')
D=rbind(Data1,Data2)

ggplot(data=D,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=tag))+geom_line()+facet_wrap(~ticks)
```

That works ok but I still needed to rename the variables.